# cloning a 2d String array in java

Tags: java, arrays, reference, clone, deep-copy

I am writing a program which has a parent node. That parent node has a 2d String array and children which contain the parents 2d String array but with a modification. However, when I am creating the children's 2d array, it keeps using the reference to the parents array. So that by the end of the children creation, the parent array has the modifications of all the children. I have tried creating a copy constructor, using System.arraycopy, Arrays.copyOf, all to no avail.
Here is the constructor

```
public class Board
{
 private String[][] Gameboard;
 public Board(Board parent)
 {
  this.Gameboard = parent.Gameboard;
 }
}
```

I have also tried looping through the arrays and assigning the strings one by one but that did not work either.
And I call the constructor like this:

```
Board temp = new Board(parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
class parent {
    static String[][] Gameboard = new String[5][5];

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                Gameboard[i][j] = "" + j;
            }
        }
        Board b = new Board();
    }
} 

class Board { 
    private String[][] Gameboard;

    public Board() { 
        this.Gameboard = parent.Gameboard; 
        for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                System.out.print("" + this.Gameboard[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }   
        System.out.print("Lenght Of Class Boar.GameBoard =" + this.Gameboard.length);  
    } 
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use copy constructor as following example:

```
public class Test {
    String[][] arr2D = new String[2][2];

    public Test() {
    }

    public Test(Test t) {
        this.arr2D = deepCopy(t.arr2D);
    }

    // deepCopy
    private String[][] deepCopy(String[][] arr2D) {
    String[][] arr2D2 = new String[arr2D.length][arr2D.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < arr2D.length; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j < arr2D.length; j++) {
            arr2D2[i][j] = arr2D[i][j];
         }
      }
       return arr2D2;
    }

    public void setArr2D(String[][] arr2D) {
        for (int i = 0; i < arr2D.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arr2D.length; j++) {
                arr2D[i][j] = i + "row " + j + "column";
            }
        }
    }

    public String[][] getArr2D() {
        return this.arr2D;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t1 = new Test();
        t1.setArr2D(t1.getArr2D());
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(t1.getArr2D()));
        Test t2 = new Test(t1);
        t2.setArr2D(t1.getArr2D());
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(t2.getArr2D()));
    }
}
```